# Can a Warlock take an Eldritch Invocation twice?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

When I reach 2nd-level on my Warlock, I gain two Invocations of my choice. I can't choose both to be Agonizing Blast, can I? Or say this is possible, would this then cause two separate instance of Agonizing Blast to trigger?

Eg: Hit with Eldritch Blast, AB1 triggers get +CHA, AB2 triggers get +CHA. Total added is +CHA*2

Seems like a ridiculous question, but it must be asked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is nothing in the rules that say you can't take the same Invocation twice. **However, there would be no benefit to taking an Invocation twice.**

This is the "ridiculous" part of the question, the wording on each Invocation actually limit themselves to confer no benefit if taken twice as most Invocations are worded as:

> ### Invocation Name
>
> You can cast [*this spell*] once using a warlock spell slot. You can't do so again until you finish a long rest.

or

> ### Invocation Name
>
> You can cast [*this spell*] at will, without expending a spell slot or material components.

Both wordings confer no benefit to taking it twice because you can still only cast [*this spell*] once until you finish a long rest (or gain a new cantrip, which, again, there's no use taking it twice). Think of it as similar to the limitations on Extra Attacks which don't stack because the wording is you can attack *twice*. *(Oh, I'm sorry, I thought the feature said EXTRA attack, not TWICE attack.* A player of mine actually said this)

---

For the specific case of *Agonizing Blast*, when you take it the second time, you add your Charisma modifier to the damage. *Sweet! Wait... Can't I already do that?* Yes. Again, taking an Invocation twice gives no benefit due to the wording.

---

### An exception to this however, is **Book of Ancient Secrets** Invocation.

If the rules are indeed interpreted as: *You can certainly take the same invocation twice but the second'll be useless*, then taking Book of Ancient Secrets twice would be tantamount to saying: *You can certainly take BoAS invocation twice, gaining 4* 1st-level *ritual spells, but you just wasted a precious class feature to gain the ability to cast an additional 2 1st-level ritual spells. Was it worth it?*

Comment: Completely agree with the other spells saying "cast once until such and such." And Agonizing Blast I agree with now, being a "when you cast" both instances won't add. Any other invocations that could cause issues (such as Lifedrinker) would come down to house rules.

Comment: I always saw the invocation choices mechanically the same as Fighting Styles, where they explicitly state you can't take a style twice. The lack of a similar statement for the invocations surprised me, until I went through the list more carefully and realized there's no real benefit to it. However, new invocations added in the future could change this, so I hope they clarify the issue at some point.

Comment: @KyleBoucher I'd have to disagree with Lifedrinker there. It is worded the same as Agonizing Blast. Yes, the creature takes _extra_ necrotic damage, but it is equal to your Charisma modifier, which is fixed and does not stack.

Comment: @DaFluid or clumsily made homebrews ;)

Comment: @daze413 PHB pg 205 Combining Magical Effects - "The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine" This would include Invocations, correct?

Comment: @KyleBoucher Spells cast through and learned from Invocations are still spells and are subject to the general rule of combining magical effects.

Comment: @daze413 Problem solved then, there is actually a rule that stops stacking of those effects (regardless of common sense, clumsy homebrews, and weird word interpretations).

Comment: @KyleBoucher Not quite. What daze413 meant is that all the Invocations that *let you cast a spell* you otherwise couldn't also make you adhere to all the other limitations of that spell (including the one you mentioned), unless a limitation is specifically lifted (e.g. not using a spell slot or not requiring a material). An Invocation by itself is not a spell, so the rule you mentioned does not apply directly. An example: you cannot cast *Sculptor of Flesh*, but you can cast *Polymorph* if you have the *Sculptor of Flesh* invocation.

Answer (score 4):

There are no rules preventing you from taking it twice if you really want to but you will only get the bonus once.

> When you cast eldritch blast, add your Charisma modifier to the damage it deals on a hit.

While you have two sources telling you to add your charisma modifier, your charisma modifier is the single value, not double. If your mod is +3, +6 is not your modifier.

A rule in a similar vein is the proficiency rules which only allow proficiency bonus to apply once even if you have multiple sources of proficiency, race and class for example.

This is ultimately a common sense rule, there are no direct rules that state you may or may not use such a combination.